# R: Coersing a plot from the plot window to a raster object

Tags: image, image-processing, raster

The following code generates the plot below in the plot window of RStudio.

```
slices <- c(10, 12,4, 16, 8)
pie(slices, col = rainbow(5))
```

I would like to coerse it to a [raster object](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/as.raster.html).

**Constraint**: I would like to avoid something like this

```
img <- readPNG(...)
img <- as.raster(img)
```

That is, I would like to avoid exporting and importing my plot.

Can you help?

[image]

Comment: can you transform your data so it's not in complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, I can (actually, the example here is just a toy example). Thx

Comment: Can you update your question so the example doesn't have complex numbers?

Comment: done xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Hm, ok so you want a raster of the RGB png. In this case it wouldn't matter if the values are compex or not. If you don't want to write to disk, you can see if there's a possibility to write it as png to memory and then read as raster.